# Passing a 2D array/matrix from C++ dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll, marshalling

I would like to pass a 2D array/matrix from a C++ dll to a C# program.
The number of rows is dynamic, while the number of columns is always 5.

I tried this with a 1D array first, and this works:

In C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int *test()
{
    int Dynamically_changing_rows = rand() & 10 + 5;
    int * oneD_array= new int[Dynamically_changing_rows];
    for (int i =0; i < Dynamically_changing_rows; i++)
    {
        oneD_array[i] = i;
    }

    return oneD_array;
}
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr test();

static void Main()
{
    IntPtr ptr = test();
    int arrayLength = Marshal.ReadInt32(Ptr);
    int[] result = new int[arrayLength];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, arrayLength);
    //Now I have the array in result array. 

    ReleaseMemory(ptr); // function to delete pointer in C++.
}
```

The problem comes when I want to do something similar with a 2D array.

In C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int **test()
{
    int **TwoD_array;
    int Dynamically_changing_rows = rand() & 10 + 5;
    TwoD_array = new int*[Dynamically_changing_rows +1];
    int columns = 5;

    // Adding some array values:
    for (int i = 0; i < (Dynamically_changing_rows +1); i++)
    {
        TwoD_array[i] = new int[columns];
        for (int j = 0; j <= columns; j++)
        {
            TwoD_array[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }
    // Save the number of rows as the first value: 
    TwoD_array[0][0] = Dynamically_changing_rows; 
}
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr test();

static void main()
{
    intPtr ptr = test();
    IntPtr ptrToPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr);
```

This gives me the correct length of the array (pointer to the first value):

```
    int arrayLength= Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptrToPtr);
```

This doesn't work:

```
    int [,] result2D = new int[arrayLength, 5];
    Marshal.Copy(ptrToPtr, result2D, 0,arrayLength);
```

Because Marshal.Copy description says: "*copies data from a one dimensional array..*"

How can I get the 2D array into `result2D[arrayLength, 5]` in C#?

I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays) on marshaling arrays, but I dident get any wiser on dynamically changing arrays.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You must allocate the size of the array before calling the c++ code and pass the size of the array of use Windows Allocate to allocate the memory.  When you call a method the data is put on the stack and the stack is not valid after returning from the method.  You can use Windows allocate in c++ and then return the pointer to the allocate memory.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand you correctly, but how can I allocate the size of the array before calling the C++ code, when it is the C++ that desides the size of the array?

Comment: Good question.  Call c++ twice.  First time return size.  Or make size large enough to handle any case.  Another option is to get 100 rows at a time and return value will return actual number of row returned.  So if you get less than 100 than you know it is the end of data.   That is why some people use the Windows Allocate and then return the allocated buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try to make size large enough since it will not be a option to call it twice. Do you have an example of how to use Windows Allocate for my example? I have been looking into it, but I cant seen to get it to work for my example of 2D arrays.

Comment: Only c++ would use Windows Allocate.  In c# you use Marshal.AllocHGlobal

Comment: Can you please show me a working example of this for 2D array? Got it working on a 1D array with Windows Allocate and Marshaling, but same problem now, cant get it to work for 2D array :/

Comment: Best way is to create a structure with the array inside the structure.  Then you can use Marshal.PtrToStructure.  The start of the array and the start of the structure will be the same memory address.  So you won't have a casting issue.